# ADO error message

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, ado

I am getting an error message while trying to update one excel table from another excel table in a different (and closed) workbook.
The error only appear when the **source workbook is not in a .xls format**.

> You cannot edit this field because it resides in a linked Excel spreadsheet. The ability to edit data in a linked Excel spreadsheet has been disabled in this Access Release.

This is supposed to be an [expected behavior](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/40448a94-1b15-4ad6-9568-62e606c29370/changing-values-in-excel-2010-xlsb-using-adodbrecordset?forum=exceldev) when using Access.

1. Why am I seeing this error as I'm not working with Access but only two Excel files, and with a more recent version than 2007 ?
2. How does this feature [improve security](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30976606/4548985) ?
3. Is there a workaround in my case ? Other than using a temp table in my target workbook.

**UPDATE : Code example**

```
Sub GetFiles()
    'Take !M sheet to create files and their informations
    Dim Base As FichierSource

    '----------------------------
    'Create files object
    '----------------------------

    'Fichier Source
    Base.Path = "C:\Users\Lichar\Documents\SQL TEST\Base.xlsx"
    Base.SourceSheet = "Data"
    Base.TargetSheet = "Base"
    Base.Columns = "*"
    Base.Filter = "WHERE [Base$].id = [Data$].id"
    Base.Name = "Base.xlsx"


    '---------------------------
    'Launch queries
    '---------------------------

    With Base
        Call UPDATEQUERY(.Path, .SourceSheet, .TargetSheet, .Columns, .Filter)
    End With

End Sub

Sub UPDATEQUERY(SourcePath As String, SourceSheet As String, TargetSheet As String, _
Columns As String, Filter As String)

    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim QUERY_SQL As String
    Dim CHAINE_HDR As String
    Dim STRCONNECTION As String

    CHAINE_HDR = "[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=5;Extended Properties='HDR=YES;'] "

    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection

    QUERY_SQL = _
    "UPDATE [" & TargetSheet & "$] INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM [" & SourceSheet & "$] " & _
    "IN '" & SourcePath & "' " & CHAINE_HDR & ") t2 " & _
    "ON [" & TargetSheet & "$].id = t2.id " & _
    "SET [" & TargetSheet & "$].ColA = t2.ColA "

    STRCONNECTION = _
    "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" & _
    "DriverId=790;" & _
    "Dbq=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
    "DefaultDir=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";ReadOnly=False;"

    Cn.Open STRCONNECTION
    Cn.Execute (QUERY_SQL)

    '--- Fermeture connexion ---
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's three questions in one, but I'll try to answer all of them:

1. It's not dependent on Access or Excel, but on the Microsoft Access OLEDB provider as far as I know. You can attempt to use an ODBC connection using the Microsoft Excel ODBC driver
2. One Stack Overflow answerer saying it's because of security reasons is not that good of a source. I doubt it's because of security reasons.
3. There are lots. If you tell us what you want to do exactly, I can be more specific.

Comment: I'm a bit lost in all those providers, drivers.. How am I supposed to use the ODBC driver ? 
Here is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46991977/openrowset-in-vba-ado-query) on what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You're not providing any code, so I can't adjust your code to use the ODBC driver. Please provide your own, I don't like to copy-paste from other questions (authorship reasons)

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific on your setup, using this code (at least most of it), I can execute update queries on a simple worksheet. Note that you can't edit linked data (expressions, linked sheets) by using an update query on the linked cell/sheet, you should edit those at the source

Comment: Added the above routine. Source is in an external wb as you can see. The tables are example tables filled with random values (no formula, no link). Note that I can do this update if source file (Base) is a .xls format. I want to achieve the update from .xlsx et .xlsm files

Comment: Ah. I believe the IN clause makes your query non-updateable. Or it's the JOIN, using a JOIN on a table with no  index (such as an Excel sheet) makes the table non updateable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157756/discussion-between-lich4r-and-erik-von-asmuth).